Edge Gateway 3200 with came with factory OS preinstalled, anyway to remove it
Have a Edge Gateway 3200 with came with factory OS preinstalled, its pretty locked down. Tried using the jumper to reset it to default but still am unable to get into the BIOS. Is there a better subtopic for this question.
